# jQuery - move background image infinitely down to up

Tags: jquery, move

I am trying to make simple car racing game and I want to move the background image down to down infinitely. Currently I have a road background image.

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var animate = $('body');
    function loopbackground() {
        animate.css('background-position', '0px 0px');
        $({position_x: 0, position_y: 0}).animate({ position_y: -2500}, {
            duration: 12000,
            easing: 'linear',
            step: function() {
                animate.css('background-position', this.position_x+'px '+this.position_y+'px');
            },
            complete: function() {
                loopbackground();
            }
        });
    }
    loopbackground();  
});
</script>
```

but the image is going up and never going down.

Comment: here is https://jsfiddle.net/jairock97/x8gvvmms/

Comment: are you trying to make it yo-yo up and down without leaving the screen? simply chain up to call down on completion, then down calls up on completion.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should enable jQuery in your jsfiddle. You can animate CSS attributes, so lets define a fake one. If you made seamless background and set exact dimensions, it gonna be an endless rolling.

```
var body = $('body');
function loopbackground() {
    body.css('background-position', '0 0');
    body.css('y_pos', 0);
    body.animate({'y_pos': -2500}, {
        duration: 12000,
        easing: 'linear',
        step: function(now, obj) {
            var element = $(obj.elem);
            element.css('background-position', '0px ' + now + 'px');
        },

        complete: function() {
            loopbackground();
        }
    });
}
loopbackground();
```

Comment: thanks you gave me clue. i just have to use repeat-y in body background image and its working fine now

Comment: You're almost done, but resetting an attribute to initial value each time is meaningful. Otherwise, animation will perform just one time.